# Automatically import project to new android studio projects

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to import the [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) (from gitHub) to any new project i create in Android studio. I know I am going to use this library in a lot of my projects so I don't want to import this project again every time. Is there a way to do this which will also set up the gradle automatically? will it work the same for jars?

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a new project and additng this to the `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```

Then, put the file aside and just paste it into any new project you create, overriding the original. There may be a way to set up a template to do this automatically.